# How to configure oracle database in eclipse kepler

Tags: eclipse, oracle, jdbc

Its a long time i am trying to connect **oracle db with the eclipse** in windows 8.

I came to know that windows 8 has removed **odbc**.

I tried to add derby library but that is not working in eclipse kepler.

When I open Database Management perspective it is not showing any DB option as mention in other tutorials.

Please help [not able to see any connection profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEE36.png)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the circle next to the drop-down, this will enable you to edit the jars for a JDBC driver. Follow the prompts from there:

[image]